# Java - Extract text between special character and word

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a String that looks like this

```
String = "Förpackning Flaska (375 ml) Förslutning Skruvkapsyl Kr/lit (104,00) Pris 39,00 kr Antal i butik 30 st Hyllplats 04-11-01 Förpackning Flaska (750 ml) Förslutning Plastkork/syntetkork Kr/lit (100,00) Pris 75,00 kr Antal i butik 16 st Hyllplats 02-03-01";
```

I want to extract some of the text inside this string. 
The end result I want is this:

"Förpackning Flaska (375 ml) Antal i butik 30 st Förpackning Flaska (750 ml) Antal i butik 16 st".

I can use the following code:

```
    name = name.replace(name.substring(name.indexOf(") ") + 2, name.indexOf("Antal")), "");
    name = name.replace(name.substring(name.indexOf("st ") + 2, name.lastIndexOf("")), "");
```

That will give me this result:

"Förpackning Flaska (375 ml) Antal i butik 30 st"

It basically does what I want it to do, but it stops after the first occurance of the pattern.

I have tried to use a regex pattern but I can't get it to work. From observing the string, I have concluded that I need a regex pattern that matches everything between ") " and "Antal". I will also need to remove the other clutter, but that is easy. My problem is that I can't seem to get my regex to work, and that would probably be the best way to do something like this. I know that I have to escape the paranthesis to make it a literal character in my regex, but I just can't get it to work.

This is the regex I've come up with and tried:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\b\\) (.+?)\bAntal");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(name);
    m.find();
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

Any help and ideas are welcome!

Comment: If you want the code does it in one line, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done in one line!

It looks like you want to remove:

- the next two words after the word `"st"`, and
- everything between `")"` and `"Antal"`

Here's the code that will do that:

```
input.replaceAll("((?<= st)( [^ ]+){2}|(?<=\\)).*?(?= Antal))", "");
```

Notes regarding the regex:

- I noticed you coded a word boundary as `"\b"`. This is a mistake - you cded a literal backspace. Instead, you code it as `"\\b"`
- I've used a regex OR expression `(A|B)` to match both in one regex
- Both regexes use a look-behind to make the replacement text a blank, which is cleaner than matching part of the input you want to keep, then putting it back, and it meant I coudl combine both regexes into one OR expression
- the `?` in `".*?"` is important - it means a non-greedy match. Without it, it will match the first bracket and the last `Antal`, skipping over any `Antal` between

Here's some test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "Förpackning Flaska (375 ml) Förslutning Skruvkapsyl Kr/lit (104,00) Pris 39,00 kr Antal i butik 30 st Hyllplats 04-11-01 Förpackning Flaska (750 ml) Förslutning Plastkork/syntetkork Kr/lit (100,00) Pris 75,00 kr Antal i butik 16 st Hyllplats 02-03-01";
    String clean = input.replaceAll("((?<= st)( [^ ]+){2}|(?<=\\)).*?(?= Antal))", "");
    System.out.println(clean);
}
```

Output:

```
Förpackning Flaska (375 ml) Antal i butik 30 st Förpackning Flaska (750 ml) Antal i butik 16 st
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It is interesting to see what one can accomplish with regex, and it really makes me want to learn more! At the moment I am focusing my Java skills on learning how to gather information on the internet to use in my programs, such as webscraping and HTML parsing. I get long strings that I want to extract data from, and regex comes in very handy!

I've saved your post for future reference, so once again, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for the replaceAll method for strings in java. It has the following signature

```
public String replaceAll(String regex, String replacement);
```

This, as the name suggests, replaces all instances of the occurence of the regular expression by the replacement text.

Comment: Thank you, Saurabh! I can't believe I missed that one!

I used 'replaceAll' and this regex and got it working:

'("\\) (.*?)Antal")'

Answer (score 0):

Try this, not sure if it will work for all of your strings, you need to approx know the max length of the description.

```
String s = "Förpackning Flaska (375 ml) Förslutning Skruvkapsyl Kr/lit (104,00) Pris 39,00 kr Antal i butik 30 st Hyllplats 04-11-01 Förpackning Flaska (750 ml) Förslutning Plastkork/syntetkork Kr/lit (100,00) Pris 75,00 kr Antal i butik 16 st Hyllplats 02-03-01";

String out = "";
Matcher mat = Pattern.compile("(Förpackning .{0,50}\\))|(Antal.{0,50}st)").matcher(s);
while(mat.find())
    out += mat.group()+" ";
System.out.println(out);
```